# Pandas convert integer zeroes and ones to boolean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains one hot encoded columns of 0s and 1s which is of dtype `int32`.

```
a     b      h1      h2     h3
xy    za      0       0      1
ab    cd      1       0      0
pq    rs      0       1      0
```

I want to convert the columns h1,h2 and h3 to boolean so here is what I did..

```
df[df.columns[2:]].astype(bool)
```

But this changed all values of h1-h3 as `TRUE`.

I also tried

```
df[df.columns[2:]].map({0:False, 1:True})
```

but that does not work either. (AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map')

What is the best way to convert specific columns of the dataframe from `int32` 0s and 1s to boolean (`True`/`False`)?

Comment: Please [provide the code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399100/13552470) to generate the dataframe.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - ya, if never first or second column integers, then is is dupe, else not.

Comment: The main logic is dupe. You can tell OP to select first two columns with `iloc` separately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can select all columns by positions after first 2 with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), convert to boolean and assign back:

```
df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].astype(bool)
print (df)
    a   b     h1     h2     h3
0  xy  za  False  False   True
1  ab  cd   True  False  False
2  pq  rs  False   True  False
```

Or create dictionary for convert columns names without first `2`:

```
df = df.astype(dict.fromkeys(df.columns[2:], bool))
print (df)
    a   b     h1     h2     h3
0  xy  za  False  False   True
1  ab  cd   True  False  False
2  pq  rs  False   True  False
```

Answer (score 4):

You were quite close with your second try. Try this

`df[df.columns[2:]].applymap(bool)`

Answer (score 3):

There is actually another option, not the most Pythonic. Nevertheless I'll provide it, can be useful if you want to convert strings (e.g.: 'Cat' versus 'Dog') to Boolean (False, True) in one step:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['xy','ab','pq'], 'b':['za','cd','rs'], 'h1':[0,1,0], 'h2':[0,0,1], 'h3':[1,0,0]})

df = df.replace({0:False, 1:True})
```

Checking for data type:

```
df.dtypes

a     object
b     object
h1      bool
h2      bool
h3      bool
dtype: object
```